# Rails NoMethodError: undefined method `image_url' for #<Image:0x00000003d95140>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, carrierwave, cloud9-ide, nomethoderror

I'm new to Rails.  I'm using Cloud9's online environment to create a simple gallery.  I'm following the RailsCast tutorial on uploading images with CarrierWave.  It worked so far, but when I try to display an image, I get "NoMethodError in Images#show. undefined method `image_url' for #" .

I tried to understand the answers to similar questions here at StackOverflow, but they were over my head.  What am I doing wrong?

The controller:

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_image, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @images = Image.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @image = Image.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @image = Image.new(image_params)

    respond_to do |format|
     if @image.save
        format.html { redirect_to @image, notice: 'Image was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @image }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @image.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @image.update(image_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @image, notice: 'Image was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @image }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
       format.json { render json: @image.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @image.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to images_url, notice: 'Image was successfully destroyed.' }
     format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_image
      @image = Image.find(params[:id])
    end

    def image_params
      params.require(:image).permit(:title, :description)
    end
end
```

The view:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
<strong>Title:</strong>
<%= @image.title %>
</p>

<p>
<strong>Description:</strong>
<%= @image.description %>
</p>

<p>
<%= image_tag @image.image_url.to_s %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_image_path(@image) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', images_path %>
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :chapters

  resources :stories

  resources :images

snipped
```

Added image_url:string column to Image model

Edited controller to read:

```
    def image_params
      params.require(:image).permit(:title, :description, :image_url)
    end
```

The error is gone. :)  Unfortunately, there's no image showing up on the website even after I restarted the server.  I'm off to figure out what the new bug is.

Comment: In config/routes.rb, do you have image resources set up?

Comment: Do you have a column named `image_url` in your **images** model? If so, then
In your image_params you only permit `title` & `description`. `image_url` is missing. So, newly created image only have the title and description value.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to figure out how to add code to my replies!  I think I have the image resources set up correctly in config/routes.rb, but I don't think I have a column named image_url in my model.  One sec while I check.

Comment: It was the lack of an image_url column in my model, and the fact that I had to add it to image_params.  Thank you, Emu!

Comment: Can you add the code from the Image model?